# Puppeteer can't click div in gmail

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to click the 3 dots on gmail here:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSHtj.png)

And then click the 'mark all as read': [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07vfb.png)

I click on the 3 dots fine.

However I cannot click on the mark all as read.

I can select it when i inspect element by: `div[class="J-M aX0 aYO jQjAxd"] > div[class="SK AX"] > div[class="J-N"]:nth-child(1)`

However i cannot click it

I have tried:

- A normal .click the selector
- .focus then .click the selector
- moving my mouse over the selector then clicking where the mouse is
- hard waits before clicking
- different selectors
- etc

  ```
            var selector = 'span[class="asa bjy"]'
            await cursor.move(selector)
            await cursor.click()
            await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" })`
  ```

This prior part is fine (uses ghost-cursor), it clicks on the 3 dots. But the following does not work

```
            await page.waitFor(1500)

            var selector = 'div[class="J-M aX0 aYO jQjAxd"] > div[class="SK AX"] > div[class="J-N"]:nth-child(1)'
            await page.waitForSelector(selector);
            await page.click(selector);
```

Any advice welcome. Please let me know if i need to add more detail.

Comment: You could try this selector: `#\:3v > div`

Comment: These randomised class and id selectors are a bad idea for targeting. Instead, look for other properties for targeting the container you want. Lastly click method doesn't work on divs; try creating a mouse click event and dispatch it on the target div.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do, but reading/writing emails via puppeteer is a lot slower than using Gmails public API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api. Using the API will make sure your code runs consistently, and won't break next time google updates some misc UI element in their HTML.

Comment: just cos hes clicking a div in gmail doesnt mean he needs to use the gmail api jeez, he could be doing a million other things